# I Need to implement/have static master data that will be use across 20-30 microservice

Tags: javascript, java, architecture, microservices

I have master static data of country,city and xyz. These data don't change frequently (once in a year).

These data will be used by multiple Microservice, I want to avoid network latency so decided not to go with another master-data-microservice.

What are the best way to implement this, considering multiple language used in MS (Java, JavaScript).

Comment: Put the data in an SQL database.

Comment: Need the same data across all MS, If I put in SQL database then I need to add that in all SQL as every MS have different SQL. I want to avoid network latency and transaction.

Comment: **Key Value** , **NoSQL , or **Key Value Cache** something. (https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/in-memory-cache.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are these things called files :-).  In days gone by, we would put data into files and use programs to read them off of disk.

Later, we decided we needed to distribute them across networks, we would use a web server to send those files to remote programs (browsers).  When we did so, the programs that used the files became slow (networks were lousy then).  And so, we developed caches.  We even put directives in files to say how long the caches were good for.  We could tune the TTL so that some files would last for seconds, others would last for days or weeks.

They even added the ability for servers to tell the programs if the files were changed on the server without sending the whole file again.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control